# Name an array depening on what is passed to it in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would I go about naming an array depending on what is passed to it. So far I have:

```
void FileIO::createMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    name = new double*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        name[i] = new double[cols];
    }
}
```

How can I go about replacing `name` with an actual name? so I can create many arrays by easily calling this method?

So, instead of creating an array called `name` I could create one called `foo`?

Comment: `foo=new double*[rows]`? What do you mean by _actual name_?

Comment: You really should not store a matrix as a double pointer.  With that if you want run time named objects you could use a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>>` and then the `string` part will be the name and the `vector` will store the matrix in a flat array.

Comment: by name, you mean the name that the one who is reading the code see?

Comment: You can't change a name. That name means nothing once the program is compiled; it is rendered down to a location in memory. If you want to have namable things, consider `std::map`

Comment: Off topic: [A simple matrix class](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please try not to use dynamic array directly until you are doing something so low-level.. the standard library full of lovely containers. Try to get the best utilization of them.

---

If my guess is right, you have something like:

```
class FileIO{
.....
    double** MatrixA;
    double** MatrixB;
    double** MatrixC;
}
void FileIO::createMatrix(int rows, int cols){
    name = new double*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        name[i] = new double[cols];
    }
}
```

You can solve your problem by something called pointer to member variable type:

```
class FileIO{
public:
    double** MatrixA;
    double** MatrixB;
    double** MatrixC;
    void createMatrix(int rows, int cols, double** FileIO::* member_varaible){
        this->*member_varaible= new double*[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            (this->*member_varaible)[i] = new double[cols];
        }
    }
};
int main(){
    FileIO fio;
    fio.createMatrix(5,5,&FileIO::MatrixA);
    fio.createMatrix(2,4,&FileIO::MatrixB);
    fio.createMatrix(4,3,&FileIO::MatrixC);
}
```

If this was the case, I think you have a bad design and you may need to think about changing it.

---

Alternative and more realistic solution:

```
namespace my_utility{
    template <typename T>
    T** create_2d_dynamic_array(int rows, int cols){
        T** temp = new T*[rows];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            temp[i] = new T[cols];
        }
        return result;
    }
}

int main(){
   auto foo = my_utility::create_2d_dynamic_array<double>(5,5);
}
```

Comment: How would this be laid out if matrixA, matrixB and matrixC were defined as private?